# The mean of running maximum

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose $W$ is a one-dimensional standard Brownian motion defined on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ and let $X(t): = \exp\{ W(t) -\frac12 t-\frac{1}{t+1}\}$ for $t \ge0$. Note that $X(\infty) :=\limsup_{t\to\infty} X(t) = 0 $ a.s. because $\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{W(t)}{t} =0$ a.s.

My question is: How to show that $\mathbb{E}[\sup_{0\le t \le \infty} X(t)] =\infty$? Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please add some context to this question with an [edit]. Where does this problem come from? What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am reading Karatzas and Shreve, Methods of Mathematical Finance, Appendix D, on optimal stopping. The problem is to show that no optimal stopping time for this example.

Comment: It is answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353046/the-mean-of-a-running-maximum/353054#353054